# From <td> to <tr> jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

Having

```
var a = $("#HTMLiFRAME").contents().find('xxx'); //only reference not actual code
```

Pointing to the object:

```
<td>hi</td>
```

In a table:

```
 <tr id="1">
     <td>hi</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="2"></tr>
 <tr id="3"></tr>
 <tr id="4"></tr>
```

How can I descend to

```
<tr id="3></tr>
```

using only methods like next(), offsetParents(), etc.

```
//ids or clases are not known
```

Comment: What the heck is this `$(document.getElementById("id"))`?

Comment: replace $(document.getElementById("id")) with $("#id"), that's the jQuery shortcut for selecting by ID.

Comment: frame or iframe? frameset frames are deprecated in HTML5. And now with the edits to your question and comments in the answer, you really need to be more specific about what exactly you're trying to select

Comment: thanks you all, answer was closest(tr) or parent() then next().next().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed (needs encapsulating table tags) and it's screwing up any DOM traversal you might hope to do. Write the HTML code correctly, use a .parent() or .closest('tr') to get from the cell to the row and then use a .next() or .nextUntil() to select the next row.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/W3yqu/

No comment on the document.getElementById inside of a jQuery selector ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var a = $("td:contains('hi')").parent().siblings().last();
```

EDIT: So you don't want the last... you want the second to last? How about this?

```
var a = $("td:contains('hi')").parent().siblings().last().prev();
```

EDIT 2: So you don't want the second to last you want... two after the first? How about this?

```
var a = $("td:contains('hi')").parent().next().next();
```

Comment: Soooooo what exactly is it that you're looking for? Number 3? The second to last? You've got to be more specific. In your original question it was the last.

Comment: So you don't know the id or class, and it's not the last or next one, and you want to select it?

Comment: I KNOW WHAT I WANT AND I JUST WANT IT! Seriously though, what is it that you're trying to select by?

Comment: take it easy bro: I want to go up to <tr id=1>, then go down 2 times to the other <tr id=2>remember, I don't know ids...

Comment: Sorry bro, just joshing. So if you go down twice from tr id=1, you'll be at tr id=3. Still not understanding what it is you want.

Comment: thanks man, ur answer did the trick too. parent().next().next(); thumbs  up :)

Answer (score 0):

Really many ways to do this. However i would have approached this differently, having in mind i will need that next selection.

```
var a = $(document.getElementById("id")),
    tbody = a.find('tbody');

var td = tbody.find('#1'),
    anotherTd = tbody.find('#2'); //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a full jquery, you could do something like this.

http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

var item = $("#1 ~ td:eq(1)")